# How to move an instance between two projects in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In compute engine, How can I move an instance from project A to project B?

I have two projects, and both have the same owner.
I looked at all the interfaces inside the console, but I could not find a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any tool in GCP that allows migrating one Compute Engine instance from one project to another.

However, it is still possible to recreate one instance from one project to another, by creating a snapshot of the disk, creating a custom image, and create a new VM from it in the second project.

[This article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-move-a-vm-instance-between-projects-on-google-cloud-platform-39d1690c73a) gives a nice step by step guide on how to do it.

Comment: Half the tools in that link are deprecated (and really, it's better to write how rather than just linking to an answer anyways....), but google has a much easier way of doing this now. I wrote another answer, hopefully it helps someone!

Comment: RMTMCKENZIE's solution below is the right one as of 2020

Comment: that post is 5 years old now

Answer (score 24):

This can be done fairly easily now, with the caveat that when you create the VM in the other project it cannot be done through the UI but rather must be done using the `gcloud` tool. And google even [has a page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects) to document how.

First, you need to either create an image or a snapshot of the disk used in the VM.  You can do this through the Console UI or the gcloud utility. [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image) does a good job of explaining how to do it, but the TLDR is:

1. stop VM if possible, or reduce number of writes by shutting down services if not
2. go to Compute Engine -> Images
3. select create
4. choose the disk as source
5. set any other properties you need
6. press create

Once that has been completed, use the gcloud tool with the other project to create your new VM. To find out/verify the name of the disk image:

```
gcloud compute images list --project [IMAGE_PROJECT]
```

then create the vm (add any additional options you need):

```
gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --image [IMAGE_NAME] --image-project [IMAGE_PROJECT]
```

Comment: Second step is probably `Compute Engine -> Images`?

Comment: Add a `--project` parameter  to `gcloud compute instances create` to define the destination project

Comment: The second step (creating a new VM from the image) can be done with the web console now. Boot disk > Custom images, select the original project, then select the image from the list.

Comment: The best approach in 2021, others doesn't work.

Comment: I've been trying to do this with a Windows Server 2019 image created from a snapshot of the source VM.  Upon initial boot, I got INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.  The disk was read-only so I mounted it on another temp VM and made it read only and then reattached it to the original VM, but now I get  ""Status: 0xc000000e                                                          
    Info: A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed. "  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer doc page to [copy VM between](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/copy-vm-between-projects) projects