# Move google cloud instance to another google account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, snapshot

So i have this google cloud account with a project i made for a friend .
Now im asked to move the project to his own google cloud account.
I tried taking a snapshot and adding him as a user and letting him make a instance with the snapshot.
But the problem is that when he logs in to his account he see's all my other projects as well.

I basically need to backup and restore the project from my account to his account without him or me having access to each other account after the migration completed

I know this might be a simple thing but i haven't figured it out yet

Thanks alot

Comment: Have a look at the answer in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501141/how-to-move-an-instance-between-two-projects-in-google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501141/how-to-move-an-instance-between-two-projects-in-google-cloud-platform)

Comment: Select the snapshot (or image) in the Google Cloud Console. The right-hand side of the page has an info panel. Click "Add members". Add your friend's email address with permissions to access the snapshot/image.

Comment: Once he has created his new instances in his project, remove his access to the snapshots/images or delete the snapshots/images.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Cloud Project Migration [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration)