# Can GCP Transfer resources between project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want transfer some resources (etc. compute engine, kubernates engine, dataproc.. )
between my projects not recreate.
Is it possible? I can't find any option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly to this answer: [How to move an instance between two projects in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501141/how-to-move-an-instance-between-two-projects-in-google-cloud-platform)
You can't move resources between projects, only option for you is to recreate them